Confusion Matrix Not Synchronized Properly in DDP with PyTorch Lightning
I am working on a typical classification task using the MNIST dataset and training with PyTorch Lightning and DDP. I am encountering an issue where the row sums in the confusion matrix are not conserved, although the sum of all elements in the matrix is correct.
Since I limit the training to 10 batches (for the debugging purposes) with a batch size of 40 on 4 GPUs, I expect the total number of samples processed to be 10×40×4=1600 samples. The sum of all elements in the confusion matrix is indeed 1600, which is correct.
Since MNIST has a fixed number of examples for each class, the sum of elements in each row of the confusion matrix should also be conserved across epochs. For example, if there are 50 examples of class "0" in a given epoch, the sum of the first row (corresponding to class "0") should add up to 50. In my case, it does not add up. My setup:
trainer = L.Trainer(
    max_epochs=opt.training.epochs, 
    accelerator=opt.device,
    devices=opt.num_devices,  # 4 GPUs
    num_nodes=opt.num_nodes,
    strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True),
    precision="16-mixed",
    limit_train_batches=10,
    limit_val_batches=10,
    reload_dataloaders_every_n_epochs=1,
    enable_progress_bar=False,
    log_every_n_steps=0,
    num_sanity_val_steps=0,
    callbacks=[top_accuracy_checkpoint, final_checkpoint],
    logger=logger
)

